# Is there anyway to improve my sql select efficiency?

Tags: python, sql

I can't make any changes to the database. And there might be millions of rows, even if I divided the numbers by 10, it still takes hours or even a whole day. So I am wondering if there is any way to improve my SQL select code?

PS: I was using python to get the data, so if there are any other ways, please let me know. Thank you.
Here is my SQL code:

```html
select a.p_id, b.f_id,c.code,c.date,c.done_price,c.zq_id
from  a, b, c
where c.zq_id = b.zq_id and b.f_id = a.f_id
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!  (Will not improve performance, just code quality.)

Comment: Show us table and index definitions. And also explain/execution plan.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share the name of your dbms name and version along with the definition of table a, b and c.

I have just used explicit join in your query to make it more readable and easier to change but it will not increase any performance.

```
    select a.p_id, b.f_id,c.code,c.date,c.done_price,c.zq_id
    from  a
    inner join b on b.f_id = a.f_id
    inner join c on c.zq_id = b.zq_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems like the problems are all because of the bad design of the database.

Comment: If possible you can share table structures along with your DBMS name so that we can give it a try. You might consider indexing to improve performance if it's not possible to change the design.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the query using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
select a.p_id, b.f_id, c.code, c.date, c.done_price, c.zq_id
from  a join
      b
      on b.f_id = a.f_id join
      c
      on c.zq_id = b.zq_id ;
```

This doesn't affect performance.  It does show familiarity with   the SQL language.

Then for performance in most databases, you want indexes.  One of the following two sets should be sufficient:

- `b(f_id, zq_id)` and `c(zq_id)`
- `b(zq_id, f_id) and` a(f_id)`

There should be no harm in having all four indexes.